# String Iteration using Iterator interface in Lists

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator, string-iteration

I was learning Collections in JAVA from a tutorial. In that during List topic I saw a line where we use a line to iterate the lists of type String in for loop using Iterator. Please refer to the piece of code below and help me to understand the concept,

```
List <String> courses = Arrays.asList("Java","Python","C");

for(Iterator iterator = courses.iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
    String course = (String) iterator.hasNext();
    System.out.println(course);
}
```

In the above code, Can someone explain this line
`String course = (String) iterator.hasNext();`
why have they give `String` in brackets()?

And, why semicolon after `iterator.hasNext();` in `for` loop

Appreciating your response in advance!!

Comment: The String in brackets is a "type casting", however it's a very old tutorial.  Choose another one.

Comment: It’s not only an old tutorial (for Java 1.5,1.6 or 1.7; Java 21 just came out). It’s also poor code for those old versions. Since Java 5 you should do `Iterator<String> iterator = courses.iterator();iterator.hasNext()`, and you would not need the cast. Just `String course = iterator.hasNext();`.

Comment: There’s a mistake in here somewhere. The initializer for the `course` variable inside the loop should be a call to `iterator.next()` as opposed to `hasNext()`. Also as pointed out elsewhere the cast and the iterator haven’t been necessary since Java 5 (2004) if one uses the “for-each” style loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. (String) is called a ["cast".](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) It converts from one type (Object) to another (String). It was more necessary before generics and parametrized types (`Iterator<String>`). Before generics, you could only get elements of type Object (the root of all types) out of a collection. If you wanted to call String methods on your element, you had to cast it to a String. This would fail at runtime if the thing was actually, say, an Integer.
2. Those semicolons are a required part of the [for loop syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1). It's usually for something to happen at the end of your iterations, normally incrementing an index variable. As you're not using an index variable, it's a noop (no operation, do nothing) in your case.

Since Java 1.5 prefer this terser syntax:

```
    for (String course : courses) {
        System.out.println(course);
    }
```

And since Java 9 use `List.of()` for creating the list (creates an immutable list, which for most purposes is advantageous):

```
    List<String> courses = List.of("Java", "Python", "C");
```

Comment: Note you can do `for (;;) { /* infinite loop */ }`, everything in the vanilla `for(;;)` loop is optional _except_ the semicolons

Comment: @Rogue Nice for illustrating that the semicolons are part of the syntax. Otherwise not recommended (it was an idiom in C). For an infinite loop in Java we are many who prefer `while (true)` as clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... In the above code, Can someone explain this line
> `String course = (String) iterator.hasNext();`
> why have they give `String` in brackets()? ..."*

This code is poorly abstracted.

Firstly, it should be the *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#next())* method, and not the *hasNext* method.

The reason *String* is in parentheses is because of the *[type-cast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) syntax*.
In this situation, a *type-parameter* for *iterator* was not declared, thus *Object* is used.

If you provide the *type-parameter* you can remove the *cast*.

```java
for(Iterator<String> iterator = courses.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
    String course = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(course);
}
```

> *"... And, why semicolon after `iterator.hasNext();` in `for` loop ..."*

That's the *[syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)*.  They are not using any *increment* value.

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Finally, just iterate *courses*.

```java
for (String s : courses) System.out.println(s);
```